# (already output) in Debug logs

Tags: apex, debugging

I am trying to add a list into an another nested list before adding values of a list to nested list it is getting the correct value but after adding i am getting (already output) in debug log when i checked.

```
 public List<String> fieldName {get;set;}
 public List<List<String>> fileValuesXML; // To get the field values of xml

for(Dom.XMLNode child : SalesforceObjecet.getChildElements()) {           
            objecetName = child.getText();
            system.debug('Object Name in XML field  ' + objecetName );

            for(Dom.XMLNode subchild : child.getChildElements()) 
            {
                system.debug('Sub child ' + subchild.getText() );
                for(Dom.XMLNode subchildfield : subchild.getChildElements())
                {
                    system.debug('Sub child Field ' + subchildfield );
                    fName  = subchildfield.getText();
                    fieldName.add(fName);
                    //fileValuesXML.add(fieldName);
                    //system.debug('Filed Name in XML field  ' + fieldName);
                }

                system.debug('Filed Name before affing to filevalueXML  ' + fieldName);                    
                fileValuesXML.add(fieldName);
                fieldName.clear();
                system.debug('Filed Name after affing to filevalueXML  ' + fileValuesXML);
            }
   }
```

I am getting values in debug log as:

> Filed Name before affing to filevalueXML  (AccountSource, field3)
>   Filed Name after affing to filevalueXML  ((), (already output),
>   (already output))

Comment: You calling fieldName.clear() for some reason. Why is that ?

Comment: to get the code cleared. when i comment clear list i get debug log as ((Name, field1, AccountNumber, field2), (already output)). Actually i need it as ((Name, field1),(AccountNumber, field2))

Comment: when i loop through the list the 0 should be (Name, field1) 1.(AccountNumber, field2) as on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        for(Dom.XMLNode subchild : child.getChildElements()) 
        {
            system.debug('Sub child ' + subchild.getText() );
            **fieldName  = new List<String> ();**
            for(Dom.XMLNode subchildfield : subchild.getChildElements())
            {
                system.debug('Sub child Field ' + subchildfield );
                fName  = subchildfield.getText();
                fieldName.add(fName);
                //fileValuesXML.add(fieldName);
                //system.debug('Filed Name in XML field  ' + fieldName);
            }

            system.debug('Filed Name before affing to filevalueXML  ' + fieldName);                    
            fileValuesXML.add(fieldName);
           // fieldName.clear();
            system.debug('Filed Name after affing to filevalueXML  ' + fileValuesXML);
        }
```

i just added another fieldName instance instead of clearing same list, if this works the problem list intialization while nesting for loops

Answer (score 0):

Just declare fieldName inside your first for loop. It will solve this issue.

```
fieldName  = new List<String> ();
```

Eg:-

```
    for(Dom.XMLNode subchild : child.getChildElements()) 
    {
        system.debug('Sub child ' + subchild.getText() );
        **fieldName  = new List<String> ();**
        for(Dom.XMLNode subchildfield : subchild.getChildElements())
        {
            system.debug('Sub child Field ' + subchildfield );
            fName  = subchildfield.getText();
            fieldName.add(fName);
            //fileValuesXML.add(fieldName);
            //system.debug('Filed Name in XML field  ' + fieldName);
        }

        system.debug('Filed Name before affing to filevalueXML  ' + fieldName);
        fileValuesXML.add(fieldName);
       // fieldName.clear();
        system.debug('Filed Name after affing to filevalueXML  ' + fileValuesXML);
    }
```